# Attribute "titleTextStyle" has already been defined

Tags: java, android, gradle

intento compilar mi proyecto pero me sale estos tipos de errores

> "Error:(2) Attribute "titleTextStyle" has already been defined"

este es mi gradle

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile project(':library')
compile project(':androidswitchbackport')
compile project(':urlImageViewHelper')
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'
compile files('libs/FlurryAnalytics-4.2.0.jar')
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.4.0@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
//compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.0'
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.1'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.3'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.7'
compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
compile 'org.apache.sanselan:sanselan:0.97-incubator'
compile 'com.cocosw:bottomsheet:1.+@aar'
compile 'org.lucasr.twowayview:twowayview:0.1.4'
compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1'
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'
```

}

Comment: Me temo es que alguna librería que estas usando esta obsoleta

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que tienes doble definición del atributo **`titleTextStyle`**, que se encuentra en más de una de tus librerías, una se encuentra en la librería:

```
compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
```

Esto va a ser un problema ya que debes tener solo una definición en tu proyecto y las librerías.

Te aconsejaría dejar de usar AndroidSherlock, si ves el proyecto tiene algo de tiempo que no es actualizadom, de hecho esta marcado como **obsoleto**:
https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock

La razón principal es que existen opciones nativas dentro del Android SDK para crear tu propio ActionBar por ejemplo usando la clase [**Toolbar**](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-toolbar-example/).

Comment: Trabajo sobre un proyecto grande ya hecho, estoy en la recta final de compilarlo y subirlo a la play store, no puedo dejar de utilizar AndroidSherlock.

Comment: Lo feo es que yo trabaje como 4 semanas sobre este código y funciono bien , y hoy de repente al sincronizar el gradle me saca este error y no me deja avanzar .

Comment: agrega el mensaje completo del error,  probablemente ahí estara la definición en otra clase para identificarla y ver alguna opción para que sigas trabajando.